# Neo4j Rounding Relationship

Tags: neo4j

everybody

I have two nodes  (S1,S2).

S1 is

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV with HEADERS FROM "file:/S1.csv" AS line
CREATE (a:S1 {ID: TOINT (line.ID)})
set a.Depth_m         =TOINT (line.depth );
```

The S1 node property vlaues are :

```
ID      Depth_m 
1       100.06
2       100.20
3       100.37
4       101.29
5       101.50
6       101.88
7       102.42
8       102.70
9       102.92
```

S2 is

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV with HEADERS FROM "file:/S2.csv" AS line
CREATE (b:S2 {ID: TOINT (line.ID)})
set b.Depth_m         =TOINT (line.depth );
```

The S2 node property values are:

```
ID     Depth_m
1       100.25
2       101.55  
3       102.75
```

So, I want to establish a relationship between the values of the two nodes,  provided in which values (Depth_m) of  S1 and S2 are approximately same (with a small difference ~ 0.5).

E.g., result should be:

```
   S1                                     S2

ID     Depth_m                         ID       Depth_m
1       100.20      =======>>          1         100.25 
2       101.50      =======>>          2         101.55
3       102.70      =======>>          3         102.75
```

Can ROUND  solves this issue? If it can do something, How I can use it?

Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

This query (for handling the `S2.csv` file) should do what you want:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV with HEADERS FROM "file:/S2.csv" AS line
CREATE (b:S2 {ID: TOINT(line.ID), Depth: TOINT(line.depth)})
WITH b
MATCH (a:S1) WHERE ABS(a.Depth-b.Depth) <= 0.5
CREATE (a)-[:SIMILAR]->(b);
```